# When are rational squares dense on a quadratic function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f\colon\mathbb Q\longrightarrow\mathbb Q$ be a function of the form $f(x)=q_2x^2+q_1x+q_0$ for $q_0,q_1,q_2\in\mathbb Q$. Say that $f$ is a *square* at $x$ if $f(x)=p^2$ for a rational number $p\in\mathbb Q$.

1) Is there some method for deciding from $q_0,q_1,q_2$ whether the set $X=\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid \text{$f$ is a square at $x$}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb Q$?

2) Can we write up an expression for all values in $X$?

Comment: Is anything lost by letting $q_2=1$ or do you want to include first degree polynomials as well?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Dividing by $q_2$, we get that $x^2+\frac{q_1}{q_2}x+\frac{q_0}{q_2}$ should be $\frac{p^2}{q_2}$, which is in general not a square. So how can we reduce to the case $q_2=1$?

Comment: If one can find conditions on $q_1,q_0$ which guarantee that $X$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}$ in the case where $q_2=1$ then the problem is solved. Perhaps my intuition is wrong, but it seems that might be an easier first approach to the problem. I see you specified quadratic in the title, so I assume you do not want to consider $q_2=0$.

Comment: Ok., I see. Then we would have a sufficient condition. Thank you for that observation!

Comment: You're welcome.